# When stopping SSHTunnel server the application hangs

Tags: python, ssh, ssh-tunnel

I have very simple script that establishes connection to another host and then creates the tunnel through which another application connects to SQL Server.

```
    self.dicSession['server'] = sshtunnel.SSHTunnelForwarder(
        ('remote_host', 22),
        ssh_username="username",
        ssh_password="password",
        ssh_private_key="key_rsa",
        remote_bind_address=('remote_host', 53425),
        local_bind_address=('localhost', 1433),
    )
    self.dicSession['server'].start()
```

It works fine. However the command to stop the server. When the connection is established I am using tunnel (between 53425 port of remote host and 1433 port of localhost) to connect to a SQL Server that operate on the remote host. Up to this point everything works fine. It seems however that stopping the SSH connection with command

```
self.dicSession['server'].stop()
```

does not work properly. Despite the command to stop the connection I am still able to execute SQL statement and get results. Moreover when I execute the SQL query after the command

```
self.dicSession['server'].stop()
```

the app - which us build with usage of PyQT5 - freezes. To be honest I have not tried to run the script without GUI but I will need the GUI as the app is not only for me but for other people who are not familiar with CLI.

Answer (score 0):

This happens because your client is still open.

It will allow you to stop server, once you closed your client.

Comment: And how exactly your answer can be helpful in solving my problem? I can conclude myself that as I can still execute SQL query the SSH connection must be opened.